# Equality dimension between the space of bounded, convergent and convergent to zero sequences

Tags: functional-analysis

Let: 
$$c(K)=\{x:\Bbb N\to K \mid \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n \text{ exists} \}\\
c_0(K)=\{ x\in c(K)\mid \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0 \}\\
l_\infty(K)=\{x:\Bbb N\to K\mid x_n \text{ is bounded}\}$$

I want to prove that:
$$2^{\aleph_0}=\dim_K(c_0(K))=\dim_K(c(K))=\dim_K(l_\infty(K))$$

So I started taking $R=\{(r^{n-1})_{n=1}^\infty:\; r\in(0,1)\}$ to show that it is linearly independent and thus $2^{\aleph_0}\le \dim_K(c_0(K))$, but got stuck.

So I took $\;a_1((r_1^{n-1})_{n=1}^\infty)+a_2((r_2^{n-1})_{n=1}^\infty)+\cdots+a_m((r_m^{n-1})_{n=1}^\infty)$ any finite linear combination of elements of $\;R$, where $\;a_i\in K\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$

So lets say that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^m a_i((r_i^{n-1})_{n=1}^\infty)=(0)_{n=1}^\infty$$
then
$$\sum_{i=1}^m (a_ir_i^{n-1})_{n=1}^\infty=(0)_{n=1}^\infty$$
then
$$\Big(\sum_{i=1}^m a_ir_i^{n-1}\Big)_{n=1}^\infty=(0)_{n=1}^\infty$$

So, fixing $\; n\in \Bbb N$ we get the next system of linear equations:
$$a_1 +a_2 +\cdots+a_m =0\\
a_1r_1+a_2r_2+\cdots+a_mr_m = 0\\
a_1r_1^2+a_2r_2^2+\cdots+a_mr_m^2 = 0\\
\vdots\\
a_1r_1^n+a_2r_2^n+\cdots+a_mr_m^n = 0$$
From here I got stuck trying to show that $a_i=0\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$
Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

---

### Update: fixing n=m

So, fixing $n=m$ we get the next system of linear equations:
$$a_1 +a_2 +\cdots+a_m =0\\
a_1r_1+a_2r_2+\cdots+a_mr_m = 0\\
a_1r_1^2+a_2r_2^2+\cdots+a_mr_m^2 = 0\\
\vdots\\
a_1r_1^m+a_2r_2^m+\cdots+a_mr_m^m = 0$$

and taking 
$$
        \bar a=\begin{bmatrix}
        a_1 \\
        a_2 \\
        \vdots \\
        a_m
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
        V=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
        r_1 & r_2 & \cdots & r_m \\
        r_1^2 & r_2^2 & \cdots & r_m^2 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        r_1^m & r_2^m & \cdots & r_m^m \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
we can rewrite the system as
$$V\bar a = 0$$
where, by Vandermonde matrix determinant:
$$det(V)=\prod_{1\le i < j\le m} (r_j-r_i)$$
And I claim that $det(V)\neq 0$, because if $det(V)=0$ then we should get that we have $i\neq j\in \{1,2,...,m\}$ s.t. $r_j=r_i$ which contradicts the fact that we took a linear combination of $m$ elements of $R$, so $det(V)\neq 0$. Thus, we can get the inverse of $V$ and operate it by the left side and get that $\bar a = 0$ which implies that $a_i = 0\;\forall i\in\{1,2,...,m\}$, for any fixed $m\in\Bbb N$. Thereby $R$ is l.i.
Since any base in $c_0(K)$ has to be at least of $ \#(R)$ elements, we get that $dim_K(c_0(K))\ge 2^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: Let $n=m$ and you have $m$ equations of $m$ unknowns, and you can write the coefficient matrix whose $j^{\text{th}}$ column contains $1,r_j,r_j^2,\cdots,r_j^m$. Maybe you could show this matrix is invertible?

Comment: So say the $mxm$ coefficient matrix is:
$$V=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\
        r_1 & r_2 & ... & r_m \\
        r_1^2 & r_2^2 & ... & r_m^2 \\
        ... \\
        r_1^m & r_2^m & ... & r_m^m
        \end{bmatrix}$$
So, it should be invertible iff $\; det(V) \neq 0$. But, 
$$det(V) = \prod_{1\le i\le j\le m} (r_j - r_i)$$

Comment: It suffices to show determinant is nonzero. It probably would not work, at first I hoped it could be transformed into some nice form for which determinant might be easy to compute, but I'm not sure now.

Comment: So, lets say $\ det(V)=0$ this would mean that $\ r_j=r_i$ for a $\ i,j\in \{1,2,...,m\}$ but this would mean that we took two same elements of $R$ and thats contradictory since we asume to take different elements. Thus, $det(V)\neq 0$

Comment: Assuming $det(V)$ is given by your formula, yes, but I don't see how you got it (That might be just me being silly though)

Comment: Its $Vandermonde matrix determinant  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: Oh, I see, I think think that's it then.  If we insist $r_i,r_j$ to be different for $i\neq j$ then determinant is nonzero, so invertible $\implies$ all the coefficients are $0$ and being slightly pendantic, in your comment above you need $i<j$ in subscript of big pi

Comment: Yes, miss that, thank you.

Comment: Any ideas to show that $dim_K(c_0(K)\le 2^{\aleph_0}$? I have reach nowhere